# how to use wintab with MinGW gcc?

Tags: gcc, mingw

I want to program with wintab, which is a standard library used by most graphics tablet manufacture.

But the library I found is not open source and sadly, its a msvc dll, only with a header.

Now I'm working with MinGW gcc.

I've tried dlltool and dllwrap in MinGW, but no luck. The libxx.a I generated can only cause my program exit.(But it links well)

What should I do to get wintab works with MinGW? Or is there a build of wintab dll from gcc?

Comment: The wintab functions use __stdcall as their calling convention despite the names being undecorated / cdecl-looking. Getting around this is relatively easy in MSVC, but there are some useful hints for MinGW [here](http://www.willus.com/mingw/yongweiwu_stdcall.html). If all else fails, there's always `LoadLibrary` and `getProcAddress`.

Comment: Thanks, @tenterhook . It is a idea on this. However, I've already changed all my platform to MSVC. I just don't understand why there's always so little support on MinGW platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WinTab with any compiler suite, but you should not be linking your application with the library, in case it is not installed on the user's system.

Instead, you should load it at runtime using `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`, as explained here:
http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/docs/WacomWindevFAQ.html#_Toc276983614

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did at last. I found Qt also use this method.

Answer (score 0):

If the Wintab DLL contains C++ code, you're out of luck. I suggest running the program in gdb to see what exactly fails.

Comment: It should be a pure C dll, because the library provides only C interface. Maybe I have to try to debug...thanks, though.